# Using QTimer to time a slideshow of 5 images

Tags: c++, qt

Is there a way to get the Qlabel to show a different image every ten seconds?

I connected my timeout signal to a slot named 'changePixmap'

```cpp
    // under ui->setupUi(this);
    QTimer *slideShow = new QTimer(this);
    connect(slideShow,SIGNAL(timeout()),this, SLOT(changePixmap()));
    slideShow->start(10000);

void MainWindow::changePixmap(){
    QString imageNumber = "1";
    ui->photoLabel->setScaledContents(true);
    ui->photoLabel->setSizePolicy( QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored );
    ui->photoLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap("image" + imageNumber + ".jpg"));
    ui->photoLabel->show();
    imageNumber = (imageNumber.toInt()+1) % 5;
}
```

The program runs and outputs one image onto the Qlabel, but it does not change to the next image.

Comment: You're changing `imageNumber`, which is a local/stack variable and therefore is discarded when the `changePixmap()` method returns, i.e. immediately after you change it.  If you want to have that change stick around, you should make `imageNumber` be a class-variable rather than a local-variable, so that the changes you make to it will still be there the next time `changePixmap()` is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

imageNumber is the variable that allows you to change the image but in your case it is always "1" so the image does not change, the last line of code does not help since the change is lost.

The solution is to make imageNumber member of the class, also it is better to be an integer.

***.h**

```cpp
// ...
private:
    int imageNumber = 0;
```

***.cpp**

```cpp
void MainWindow::changePixmap(){
    ui->photoLabel->setScaledContents(true);
    ui->photoLabel->setSizePolicy( QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored );
    ui->photoLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap(QString("image%1.jpg").arg(imageNumber));
    ui->photoLabel->show();
    imageNumber = (imageNumber + 1) % 5; 
}
```